# Style array_slice output

Tags: php, styles, output, slice, implode

I have the following PHP script that extracts the last 5 rows from file X.

```
<?php
$f=file("x.txt");
$last=array_slice($f, -5);
echo implode("<br>",$last);
?>
```

The output is the following:

```
John
Christmas
George
Luck
Sun
```

Question: How can I make the output to be clickable links? Example of output I want:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=John">John</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=Christmas">Christmas</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=George">George</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=Luck">Luck</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?q=Sun">Sun</a>
```

I tried something like:

```
echo implode("<br> <a href='http://google.com/q?' . $last . ''>");
```

But it didn't work at all... any solutions? Thanks!

Comment: `echo "<br> <a href='http://google.com?q=".$last."'>".$last."</a>";`

Comment: Thanks for that, @ShadowFiend. But if I do that, the output it will be the link Array. (nothing from the list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `implode()`, you can just loop thru `$last` then echo desired html line

```
foreach ($last as $value) {
    echo "<a href='http://www.google.com?q=$value'>$value</a><br>";
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Mark as accepted if it works/solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
<?php
    $names = array('John','Christmas','George','Luck','Sun');
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo "<br><a href=\"http://www.google.com?q=$name\">$name</a>";
    }
?>
```

Happy Coding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to use `implode` function.

I have modified your code as below. Hope this will help.

```
<?php 
$f=file("x.txt");
$last=array_slice($f, -5);

if(!empty($last)){
    foreach ($last as $value) {
      ?>
      <a href='http://www.google.com?q=<?php echo $value;?>'><?php echo $value;?></a><br>
      <?php

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$f = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"); //$f=file("x.txt");
$last=array_slice($f, -5);
echo implode("<br>",$last);

foreach ($last as $value) {
    echo "<a href='http://www.google.com?q=$value'>$value</a> , ";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_map and implode if you don't want to loop.

```
$last = array('John','Christmas','George','Luck','Sun');

function addlink($last)
{
  return('<a href="http://www.google.com?q=' . $last .'">' . $last .'</a>');
}

$last = array_map("addlink",$last);
echo implode("\n", $last);
```

https://3v4l.org/l3nME